# accessing a 3d array

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

my understanding of php and how to use multi-dimensional arrays is limited so i am struggling to understand how to access name="value".

```
<input name='questions[]' type='text' value='question 1' /><br/>
  <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 1' />   
    <input name='value[1-1][1][]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>
  <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 2' />   
    <input name='value[1-1][2][]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>
  <input name='choice[1-1][]' type='text' value='option 3' />   
    <input name='value[1-1][3][]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>
```

I have used a foreach loop and access it that worked, but I want to access a single element in the value array. so I believe that using an alternate method would be better.

I have accessed questions[] by:

```
$q = $_POST['questions'];
echo $q[0];
```

but I tried to access choice[] and value[] in a similar way, but without success.

Firstly I tried print_r() to see how the array was set up, I saw i needed extra [] for choice and two extra for value, but I added them and got the error message, Undefined offset: 0, which from research I have found means that array is not set, I am obviously accessing it incorrectly, can someone please advise.

Also advice on a good tutorial for multi-dimensional arrays can be found would be appreciated, ive already looked at php.net.

Comment: wouldn't using 1 array be easier for you?

Comment: 3D Array: $arr[x][x][x], To cycle through this you would need three loops, each nested in the previous one.

Comment: Dagon, I started with a single array, but need the script to know that each one is linked and was advised that multi dimensional arrays would be best. Choices needs to be linked to questions and values linked to choices

Comment: Steve thanks for your message, but I have tried that way, and it did work. However I am want to output a single element is a specified placed, rather than all the elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of telling you exact answer, let me guide you with the hint so that you can learn and get the fun yourself.

use:

```
    print_r($_POST);
```

with the result you'll be able to decide how to call each element. If you still have problem just comment below.

Comment: Lenin, thanks for your response, I have looked at the information print_r() produces and I am not getting any further. I have tried $_POST['choice'][1-1][0] and the same error message appears

Comment: you cannot write like `$_POST['choice'][1-1][0]`

Why did you choose such array subscripts?

Comment: This form is generated dynamically based on how may question and options the user chooses. It then gets passed onto another page once the input boxes have been filled in an I need to be able to link how many options are with each question. I was advised that a multi-dimensional array was best to do this. I then assumed that adding another dimension to the array would link each value with each option......hope that makes sense

Comment: But is the generated subscript [1-1]? If that is then use like:
`$_POST['choice']['1-1'][0]`

Comment: I now see that I was missing the '' wrapping around the 1-1. Thanks for the assistance Lenin

Comment: You also missed what @Googleguy already suggested you too. :)

Comment: No, that's how i got the answer, badly worded on my part. A big thanks to you and all who helped

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easier to process via php than your current structure

```
<input name='questions[q1]' type='text' value='question 1' /><br/>
<input name='questions[choice][1]' type='text' value='option 1' />   
<input name='questions[value][1]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>
<input name='questions[choice][2]' type='text' value='option 1' />   
<input name='questions[value][2]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>  
<input name='questions[choice][3]' type='text' value='option 1' />   
<input name='questions[value][3]' type='text' value='value' /><br/>
```

i can see a few variations on this depending on your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is how PHP will populate the array (*$_GET/$_POST -- depending on the form method*) when this form is submitted. Anything inside of the square brackets is literal (with the exception of a few characters like under-scores, which are translated to dashes). Empty brackets means PHP will automatically append each value to that array (starting from a 0 index) as if you used `array_push` in PHP.

So your array would like this...

```
$_POST['value']['1-1'][1][0] = 'whatever value the user supplied 1';
$_POST['value']['1-1'][2][0] = 'whatever value the user supplied 2';
$_POST['value']['1-1'][3][0] = 'whatever value the user supplied 3';
```

To access any of those elements in PHP you would use that same notation. If you wanted to iterate over them you'll have to consider that they are three dimensional. So for example...

```
foreach ($_POST['value']['1-1'] as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
```

This would output

```
whatever value the user supplied 1
whatever value the user supplied 2
whatever value the user supplied 3
```

Also, I forgot to mention that you can use something like var_dump($_POST, $_GET); to look at a printable the structure of the array. I highly recommend [var_dump](http://php.net/var-dump) for debugging variables, because it gives you a lot of useful information about those variables that goes above and beyond any other function like print_r/echo/etc...

Comment: So using $_POST['choice'][1-1][0] or $_POST['choice'][1-1][1][0] should work? This is where I am getting stuck as it is not. Although it works fine when I nest two foreach loops for choice and three foreach loops for value

Comment: No,  $_POST['choice'][1-1][0] and $_POST['choice'][1-1][1][0] are both wrong, but for two different reasons. The first is wrong because you need to quote string literals. `1-1` is an expression that means means do the arithmetic operation of **subtracting one from one**, thus giving you `0`. The second is wrong because of the same reason, but also because you're suing three dimensions and it's only a two-dimensional array.

Comment: The code I supplied you with above works exactly as it should, because it takes into account that you asked how to access `values`. For `choices` replace the first foreach with `foreach ($_POST['choices']['1-1'] as $value) {` and remove the second foreach completely and use `$value`.

Comment: Google guy, thanks for the lesson :D I cant believe I didn't see that myself.

Comment: No problem. It happens to everyone.